# How to detect whether webpage is running in iPhone's embeded browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have a webpage that uses custom protocol handlers to open apps. One links to the iTunes store app for people to download Picup app, and another links to fileupload:// to open the Picup app.

When the page is loaded into Safari embedded inside another app (e.g. 1Step Scanner barcode scanner), when navigating to those custom protocols, I get an error message - Error, Failed to Load Webpage! Please Try Again.

I intend to use JavaScript to detect whether the webpage is loaded inside an embedded browser and show a message to ask the user to use Safari.

One way is to detect the user agent string

Embedded

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405
```

Safari

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
```

However, is detecting the presence/absence of the word Safari in the user agent string applicable for all versions of iPhone? Is there a more foolproof method?

Comment: I must warn you that this is easily spoofed and if the user is using another browser like dolphin, or another one, you should give them the option to launch the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yes, that's the best way.

Even Chrome for iOs includes the word Safari on requests, so you should be fine with assuming that requests from iOs without the word "Safari" are from an embedded UiWebKit control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom User-Agent for your requests ... here's an example :

```
NSString *urlString= @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[requestObj setValue:@"myCustomAgent_Mathboy:)/1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: What I have is a webpage, not an iPhone app. I need to detect whether the user is visiting my webpage in Mobile Safari or with another app

Comment: Didn't get your question . Sorry